# Can I save installed packages when I need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, package-management

Last night my Ubuntu system was working fine but today its getting stuck at the start screen. I can tell you my system states that Grub is working fine. My system is dual boot with Windows 7 as my other OS. and I can work on it. I have tried recovery mode options, dkgp and fsck. but still no success.  I don't have a graphics card.

I think that the only thing that is left for me to try is reinstall, but I have installed many package and spent so much time on it.

Is there a way to keep all those packages intact?  Or is there any other alternative solution?  I really don't want to spent time on installation of all those dependencies again.

Comment: If you heavily customized your system without keeping backups or notes, then one hopes you have learned from the experience. Consider opening a much more detailed question about the boot problem - it may be easily fixable.

Answer (score 1):

Install SystemBack and backup all your ubuntu system.

You save it as a .iso file and install it like usually (usb or cd).

Here you will keep all your applications, session, configurations, and if you want, your personal data (photos, files,etc).

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --yes ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

Comment: Ok so after I install system back I will be creating .iso save it in usb, reinstall my ubuntu and then install back my packages. Am I right?

Comment: but i m not able to load my OS .

Comment: Once **systemback finished** you save your `new .iso` into a usb stick or burn on a cd. It has to be booteable. I suggest you to use `Linux Live USB Creator`.  You will install your new iso (your ubuntu+personal data and applications,etc). It`s a copy of your linux installed, so you already have all your applications installed and configurated in the iso file. Install it without remove windows, later on u can configure Grub to make dual boot. Follow this link: [systemback tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aie2xRR0w1Y)

Comment: if the system is broken, what makes you think the image of it made by systemback will work?

Comment: He wanted to know how to reinstall ubuntu without reinstalling all the applications he installed. So, if it doesn´t work when the systemback live cd is running, or when installation procces it´s done but with problems, that´s when it´s time to reinstall the  Clean install Ubuntu Linux or think about other options to fix it. I just try to help!

Comment: Please add the additional info into the answer, as comments are not necessarily permanent.

Comment: So I had Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, and I upgraded it to 14.04.5 from flashdrive. This solved my issue and now I am able to access all my documents and installed packages, just as before the crash. Thats exactly what I required.